# get cell.textField values in function

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift

I've created a UITableView with customCells one with a textField and one with textView. When the user is pressing the UIBarButtonItem with the title "Done" I want to save the textField values, but how do I access those values outside cellForRowAtIndexPath?

Comment: Keep reference of them in a list

Comment: Could u give an example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < [self.tableView numberOfRowsInSection:0]; i++) {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:i inSection:0]];
    // do something with cell
}
```